# Java, swing, panel and textarea, won't change the colour, possible refference is wrong

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to make a frame, in it panel to control actions and a `TextArea` to somehow react after mouse did sth in control panel. Dunno why it doesn't want to change the state of `TextArea` (background color) when mouse is pressed within the control panel (north panel).
I guess there is sth wrong with a reference to `textArea` object within `MouseEventHandler` class, but don't know how to fix it. I searched with `getSource()` method and it seems i was right, but dunno how to make it right.

Main

```
package MainPackage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            // Draw a frame
            final DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame(500, 500);
            // Add yes-no confirmation of closing the application
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    int confirmInt = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                            "Are you sure?", "Exit confirmation",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                    if (confirmInt == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                }

            });

            // Create a textField
            JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();

            //Set textField's variables
            textArea.setBackground(Color.RED);
            textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
            frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            // Add a drawPanel
            JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            //Set drawPanel's variables
            drawPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            drawPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseEventHandler(textArea));
            frame.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            //Set frame visible
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });




}




}
```

DrawFrame

```
package MainPackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8914767267085394262L;


public DrawFrame(int width, int height) {
    setSize(width, height);
    setTitle("MouseTest");

}

}
```

MouseActions
    package MainPackage;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

class MouseEventHandler extends Main implements MouseListener

{   private JTextArea textArea;

public MouseEventHandler(JTextArea textArea)
{
    textArea = this.textArea;
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    textArea.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
}
}
```

Comment: Somwhere in the code glitches events.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your MouseEventHandler Constructor. It should be:

```
public MouseEventHandler(JTextArea textArea) {
    this.textArea = textArea;
}
```

than it works. And the panel is blue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's about how you reference the `textArea`.

You could declare it as a `protected` member in the `Main` class.

```
protected static JTextArea textArea;
```

And then, you don't need to do anything on the constructor `public MouseEventHandler(JTextArea textArea)` because `textArea` will already reference to the one you declared as `protected` in the `Main` class, since 
`MouseEventHandler` extends it.

As said on another answer, switching

```
textArea = this.textArea;
```

to

```
this.textArea = textArea;
```

also solves your problem.

Comment: -1, there is no reason to make the variable static. Read pL3Gu33's answer for the simple solution, which was given 4 minutes earlier.